# jquery autocomplete source not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I copy the source code from [jQuery autocomplete demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) and replace relative url as absolute url, but when I test the page in localhost, the autocomplete widget doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote with caching</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-loading {
                background: white url('http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#birds").autocomplete({
                    source: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php",
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="birds">Birds:</label>
            <input id="birds" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make requests to other hosts. localhost is not the same as jqueryui.com so you are being blocked by the [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Comment: I replace source as `"http://localhost/mirt_search.php"`, this page would response as described in autocomplete doc. But it still does not work. What's wrong

Comment: @Derek `http://localhost/mirt_search.php?term=200` return a json data, and apache log have no warning/errors.

Comment: @Zhao - It doesn't work might be because of the data returned, since when I replaced your link with an Array, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/n4v5G/

Comment: @Derek the widget works when I cope the returned data from mirt_search.php?term=xxx into search field. but set to `source: "mirt_search.php"` doesn't work

Comment: @Zhao - Then probably it is because of the same origin policy.

Comment: @Derek I found the bug, my return data have an addition ',' after the last element which cracks `[{label:"hsa-miR-20a"},{label:"hsa-miR-20b"},]`. Thank you for your time:)

Comment: @Zhao - It's great that you found where's the problem at. :)